# How to get selected item of the comboBox and save it as intiger

Tags: qt, combobox

I have a comboBox in Qt and the comboBox has three items (first task, second task, third task). If the user chooses the first task I want to set Mode=0 and if the user selects the second task I want to set Mode=1. How can I do This? I have tried

```
 Mode_t=ui->comboBox->itemData(ui->comboBox->currentIndex()).toInt();
```

but it doesn't work. it sets Mode=0 for all cases.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be like that:

```
 Mode_t = ui->comboBox->currentIndex() + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks 'Mode_t = ui->comboBox->currentIndex() ' for my case is better. @GeneCode

Answer (score 0):

You can add QVariant data to you items, and return mode/string...:

```
QComboBox comboBox;
comboBox.addItem("1", 23);
comboBox.addItem("2", 34);
comboBox.setCurrentIndex(1);
qDebug() << comboBox.currentData(); // write 34
```

if items are exist:

```
cb.setItemData(0, 23);
cb.setItemData(1, 34);
```

And you code will work too